# RxJS - make counter with reset stateless?

Tags: javascript, counter, rxjs

Assuming I have the following markup:

```
<button id="dec">-</button>
<output id="out">0</output>
<button id="inc">+</button>
<button id="res">RESET</button>
```

And the following Rx.js script:

```
var total = 0

Rx.Observable.merge(
    // decrement
    Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#dec'), 'click')
    .map(function() { return -1 }),

    // increment
    Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#inc'), 'click')
    .map(function() { return +1 }),

    // reset
    Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#res'), 'click')
    .map(function() { return -total })
) // merge
.forEach(function(delta) {
    total += delta
    $('#out').text(total)
})
```

Everything works as expected.  Clicking the +/- increments/decrements the counter, and clicking 'RESET' resets it back to zero, but...I have the variable 'total' at the top.  This is state, which if I subscribe to the values of functional reactive programming, is evil, no?  If so, how do I remedy this?  If I didn't have the reset button, I could just use `scan(seed, accumulator)`, but the functionality of the reset button is throwing me for a loop, as to how to do it 'stateless'.

[Working fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/jrop/8z34ggk1/3/).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two ways of going about this that I can see.

First, there is nothing that says you can't augment your data in the pipeline:

```
Rx.Observable.merge(
  // decrement
  Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#dec'), 'click')
    .map(function() { return {delta : -1}; }),

  // increment
  Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#inc'), 'click')
    .map(function() { return {delta : +1}; }),

  // reset
  Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#res'), 'click')
    .map(function() { return {reset : true}; })
) // merge
.scan(0, function(acc, value) {
  return value.reset ? 0 : acc + value.delta;
})
.forEach(function(delta) {
  $('#out').text(delta)
});
```

The above lets you signal downstream that the stream has been reset by adding in a field (note: I cheated, for readability you might want to add `reset : false` rather than rely on falsey-ness, but it's up to you).

Alternatively, if you think of the `reset` as actually resetting the stream then you could instead use `flatMapLatest` to wrap the incrementing and decrementing:

```
Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#res'), 'click')
.startWith(null)
.flatMapLatest(function(e) {
  return Rx.Observable.merge(
    // decrement
    Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#dec'), 'click')
      .map(function() { return -1 }),

    // increment
    Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#inc'), 'click')
      .map(function() { return +1 })
  )
  .scan(0, function(acc, delta) { return acc + delta })
  .startWith(0);
})
.subscribe(function(value) {
   $('#out').text(value) 
});
```

This makes the stream a little bit messier than it has to be with the inclusion of two `.startWith`s to kick off the respective sequences, but if you were opposed to augmenting and wanted the state implicitly controlled by the stream then this would be an approach.

Comment: I think the first option is the easiest to read.  The second one is pretty clever, thanks for taking the time to answer!

Answer (score 8):

Following @paulpdaniels answer, here is what i'm using with Ramda:

```
var hardSet  = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#set');
var decRes   = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#dec');
var incRes   = Rx.Observable.fromEvent($('#inc');

Rx.Observable.merge(
  incRes.map(function()  { return R.add(1); }),
  decRes.map(function()  { return R.add(-1); }),
  hardSet.map(function() { return R.always(0); })
).scan(function(prev, f) { 
  return f(prev); 
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 2):

@Jrop I like this operator [`Rx.Observable.when`](http://xgrommx.github.io/rx-book/content/observable/observable_methods/when.html). With this one you can reproduce [`Bacon.update`](http://baconjs.github.io/api.html#bacon-update) very easy. This is my code and [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/gemore/2/edit?js,output) example:

```
const {when, fromEvent} = Rx.Observable;

const decObs = fromEvent(document.getElementById('dec'), 'click');
const incObs = fromEvent(document.getElementById('inc'), 'click');
const resetObs = fromEvent(document.getElementById('res'), 'click');

when(
    decObs.thenDo(_ => prev => prev - 1),
    incObs.thenDo(_ => prev => prev + 1),
    resetObs.thenDo(_ => prev => 0)
).startWith(0).scan((prev, f) => f(prev))
.subscribe(v => document.getElementById('out').innerHTML = v);
```

Also will be better if you look at this [`Join-calculus`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join-calculus), [`New Release and Joins`](http://codebetter.com/matthewpodwysocki/2010/04/19/introduction-to-the-reactive-extensions-for-javascript-new-release-and-joins) and this [`Combining sequences`](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/12_CombiningSequences.html#AndThenWhen)

Answer (score 1):

Here is how it (reset + input for changing step) could be accomplished RxJs v6:

```js
const { fromEvent, merge } = rxjs;
const { map, mapTo, startWith, scan, withLatestFrom } = rxjs.operators;

const resultEl = document.getElementById("js-result"),
  stepInpEl = document.getElementById("js-step-inp"),
  btnDecEl = document.getElementById("js-btn-dec"),
  btnIncEl = document.getElementById("js-btn-inc"),
  btnReset = document.getElementById("js-btn-reset");

// observables (5)
const step$ = fromEvent(stepInpEl, "input").pipe(
  startWith({ target: { value: 5 } }),
  map(e => Number(e.target.value))
);

const inc$ = fromEvent(btnIncEl, "click").pipe(
  withLatestFrom(step$),
  map(([e, step]) => step )
);

const dec$ = fromEvent(btnDecEl, "click").pipe(
  withLatestFrom(step$),
  map(([e, step]) => -step )
);

const reset$ = fromEvent(btnReset, "click").pipe(
  mapTo( 0 )
);

const counter$ = merge(dec$, inc$, reset$).pipe(
  startWith( 0 ),
  scan((acc, value) => value && acc + value)
);

// subscriptions (2)
counter$.subscribe(val => resultEl.innerHTML = val);
step$.subscribe(val => stepInpEl.value = val);
```

markup:

```
<h2>RxJS (v6) counter</h2>
<em>5 observables, 2 subscriptions</em>
<h3>Result: <span id="js-result"></span></h3>

<button id="js-btn-reset">Reset</button>

<input type="number" id="js-step-inp" class="stepInp">

<button id="js-btn-dec">Decrement</button>

<button id="js-btn-inc">Increment</button>
```

Live example on [codepen](https://codepen.io/_danko/pen/RwwpEde)