# use .startWith() value later, How to?

Tags: rxjs

> I draw a triangle and I want rotate it on my screen

```
    var k_rotate = Rx.Observable.fromEvent(document, 'keydown')
        .filter(function (evt) { return evt.which === 37 || evt.which === 39; })
        .map(function (event) {
```

> Inside centroid() I want to acces the startWith value to find out the center of the triangle

```
            centroid();
            return { here I should return the rotate coordinates };
    })
        .startWith({
            a: { x: (canvas.width / 2) - SHIP_WIDTH, y: canvas.height / 2 },
            b: { x: canvas.width / 2, y: (canvas.height / 2) + SHIP_WIDTH },
            c: { x: (canvas.width / 2) + SHIP_WIDTH, y: canvas.height / 2 }
        });
```

Comment: Please state what you have tried, try to make your code more complete and what your question is.

Comment: If I understand what you are asking you can probably use approaches from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434606/rxjs-make-counter-with-reset-stateless).  However, I'd recommend using a behavior subject.

Comment: guys thanks for your reply, I'll try to sharp my code and my question. It's hard to me because I don't have previous experience with rxjs.