# Adding to previous result, Observable pipeline only running once

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5, rxjs6

[live example](https://rxjs-playground.github.io/#/?html=%3Cbutton%20onclick%3D%22addFilter%28%29%22%3Eadd%3Cbutton%3E&js=let%20filters%24%20%3D%20new%20Rx.BehaviorSubject%28%5B%5D%29%3B%20%0Alet%20id%20%3D%200%3B%0A%0Afilters%24.subscribe%28f%20%3D%3E%20console.log%28f%29%29%3B%0A%0Afunction%20addFilter%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20filters%24.first%28%29%0A%20%20%20%20.map%28filters%20%3D%3E%20%28%5B...filters%2C%20%7B%20id%20%7D%5D%29%29%0A%20%20%20%20.subscribe%28filters%24%29%3B%0A%20%20id%2B%2B%3B%0A%7D)

I've an Array of Filters as an `Observable` and I'd like to add/remove filters from it. Here is the code I have that is currently only adding a `Filter` the first time the function runs.

The second time nothing happens.

```
private _filters$ = new BehaviorSubject<Filter[]>([]);

addFilter(added: Filter) {
    debugger
    // adding to array of filters
    this._filters$.pipe(
        tap(d => { debugger; }),
        first(), 
        map(filters => ([...filters, added]))
    ).subscribe(this._filters$);
}
```

So my question is: why does this happen ? Why does it run only once ? (By the way `first()` is not the reason).

I know I can make the code work like so:

```
private _filters$ = new BehaviorSubject<Filter[]>([]);

currentFilters;

init() {
   this._filters$.subscribe(f => this.currentFilters = f);
}

addFilter(added: Filter) {
    this._filters$.next([...this.currentFilters, added]);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is because of `first`. When you run the function the first time it is creating the stream and subscribing to the `BehaviorSubject`. When it receives the first event it forwards it to `BehaviorSubject` and then it completes `BehaviorSubject`. The second time you run it `BehaviorSubject` is already shutdown so it immediately unsubscribes any new subscriptions to it.

Without knowing too much about your actual goal my suggestion is that instead of putting the `BehaviorSubject` at the bottom of the pipeline you instead put it at the top.

```
// You don't actually need the caching behavior yet so just use a `Subject`
private _filters$ = new Subject<Filter>()

// Hook this up to whatever is going to be using these filters
private _pipeline$ = this._filters.pipe(
  // Use scan instead mapping back into self
  scan((filters, newFilter) => ([...filters, newFilter]), []),
  // Store the latest value for new subscribers
  shareReplay(1)
);

// Now this method is just pushing into the `Subject` and the pipeline never has to be torn down
addFilter(added: Filter) {
    debugger
    this._filters$.next(added);
}
```

Comment: I should have double checked for the `first`, I might have had another that blocked it in my real code. Concerning your answer I see one issue and one question.
The issue is that _pipeline$ is what we are subscribing to but it assumes we are only adding filters. While in my case I do remove / add. The question is did you use `shareReplay(1)` instead of using a `BehaviorSubject` at the top to avoid additional computation when subscribing ?

Comment: For the issue that you mentioned I would suggest you have a look at another SO question which has a similar issue (deals with numbers not arrays but the principle would be the same) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31434606/rxjs-make-counter-with-reset-stateless/31435486#31435486. I switched the logic to use `shareReplay` because it is more semantic and less error prone. Using raw subjects to do state management is generally considered an anti pattern because more often then not you will end up leaking state, as you ended up discovering. Operators tend to manage their own life cycles.

Comment: Ok thank you, it looked quite complicated for my use case so I ended up using what i ve in my snippet in my question. Any counter indication on using that instead ?